# nodejs синтаксис UPDATE

Tags: node.js, update

```
arr['phone'] = connection.escape(arr['phone']);
arr['timestamp'] = connection.escape(arr['timestamp'].toString());
arr['date'] = connection.escape(arr['date']);

let sql = 
{
    'date': arr['date'], 
    'timestamp': arr['timestamp'], 
    'phone': arr['phone']
};

let updateReq = 'UPDATE crm_requests SET date = ?, timeSort = ? WHERE phone = ?';
connection.query(updateReq, sql, function(err, res)
{
    if(err) throw err;
});
```

[image: скриншот]

Что я делаю не так? Как правильно прописать синтаксис, чтобы это работало?

Answer (score 0):

```
var phone = connection.escape(arr['phone']);
var timestamp = connection.escape(arr['timestamp'].toString());
var date = connection.escape(arr['date']);

var query = 'UPDATE crm_requests SET ? WHERE phone = ?';
var args = [{ date, timeSort: timestamp }, phone];

connection.query(query, args, function(err, res) {
  if(err) throw err;
  console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Нет, он не обновил так ничего.

Comment: @blaccyee, а что получилось?

Comment: Так сработало
let query = 'UPDATE crm_requests SET date = ? , timeSort = ? , vtorCall = ? WHERE phone = ?';
    let args = [ arr['date'], arr['timestamp'], "vtorCall", arr['phone'] ];
    
    connection.query(query, args, function(err, res)
    {
     if(err) throw err;
     else 
      console.log('Increased the salary for Joe.');
    });

Comment: И еще такой вопрос, я использую connection.escape(arr['phone']). После escape он не обновляет поле. Как в этом случае правильно использовать escape он инъекций?

Comment: Он добавляет кавычки, поэтому не в запросе ошибка получается. Как этого избежать?